# std::move required on return of std::unique_ptr for Intel but not GCC and Clang

Tags: c++11, c++14, move-semantics, unique-ptr, icc

I have a function that returns a unique_ptr as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> createMyClass( ... )
{
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> my_unique_ptr;
    // Some code that populates my_unique_ptr
    return my_unique_ptr;
}
```

This function compiles with recent versions of GCC and Clang with -std=c++14, but the Intel compiler (icpc 15.0.3 20150408) complains that default_delete is inaccessible ("error #373"). If I replace the return statement with

```
    return std::move(my_unique_ptr);
```

then the Intel compiler is able to compile the code. I was under the impression that copy elision applies at function returns, so std::move is superfluous. Why does Intel want an explicit std::move?

I am on OS X Mavericks, so Intel is linking against libc++, if that matters.

Comment: This isn't exactly copy elision, but a related rule that says that constructors from rvalue references are considered for return statements in situations similar to those in which copy elision applies.

Comment: [Works on ICC 13](https://goo.gl/ZIcvZz) with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Changing -std=c++14 to -std=c++11 fixes it, thanks.